# sudo apt-get -y upgrade taking to long 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 20.04

I want to install a new package so, I need to `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` but it just keeps going on and on and on with the below output. I am not able to understand the concepts of `sudo apt-get`. I mean `update`/`upgrade`. Please help me.

**Note:-**  Editing this because it completed after 1:30 hours but it causes few problems. My system behaves strangely. My fonts got changed, all system icons changed

**how can i get back my system fonts and icons?**

```
Unpacking fonts-lohit-telu (2.5.5-2) over (2.5.5-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../327-fonts-noto-cjk_1%3a20190410+repack1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-noto-cjk (1:20190410+repack1-2) over (1:20190410+repack1-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../328-fonts-opensymbol_2%3a102.11+LibO7.0.0~rc2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-opensymbol (2:102.11+LibO7.0.0~rc2-1) over (2:102.11+LibO6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice': Directory not empty
Preparing to unpack .../329-fonts-sarai_1.0-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-sarai (1.0-3) over (1.0-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../330-fonts-telu-extra_2.0-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-telu-extra (2.0-5) over (2.0-4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../331-fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf_1%3a0.7.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf (1:0.7.2-1) over (1:0.7.1-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../332-fonts-tlwg-garuda_1%3a0.7.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-tlwg-garuda (1:0.7.2-1) over (1:0.7.1-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../333-fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf_1%3a0.7.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf (1:0.7.2-1) over (1:0.7.1-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../334-fonts-tlwg-kinnari_1%3a0.7.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-tlwg-kinnari (1:0.7.2-1) over (1:0.7.1-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../335-fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf_1%3a0.7.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf (1:0.7.2-1) over (1:0.7.1-3
```

Comment: A mangled system is a consequence of not checking the system's proposed changes before agreeing. You told the system to do that with the `-y` flag.

Comment: @user535733 how can I get back my system fonts and icons?

Comment: @DilipTarkhala https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/how-to-change-ubuntu-desktop-font to reset fonts

Comment: -1 because the question is misleading: Looking at the package versions, seems like you release-upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10.  A normal update/upgrade cannot change `fonts-sarai` from 1.0-2 (16.04/18.04/20.04) to 1.0-3 (20.10). There is no going back. You must reinstall 20.04, or stay with 20.10.

Comment: @user535733 oh I see, My OS auto changed to Kali GNU/Linux Rolling from 20.04
After upgrade

Comment: Please note Kali is off-topic on this site. You added the *kali* sources before you `sudo apt update` (updated your system software lists) then `sudo apt upgrade` (upgraded packages) and gave permissions ('-y' means you gave permission without reading consequences) for the changes, so the best way back is via restoration of your backups, otherwise a re-install, but you're no longer running Ubuntu currently.  Package tools upgrade to the latest packages available in your lists, so be careful adding unofficial sources!

Comment: is reinstalling ubuntu is the only option to get back to ubuntu20.04?

Answer (score 1):

`apt update` (in the latest version you don't need the `apt-get` command for most purposes) will search your sources (which are stored in `/etc/apt/sources.list`) for all new updates.

`apt upgrade` will fetch all updates and then install them.

In the words of @user535733, your system keeps a local database of all the packages available from all the sources that it knows about. `apt` must update that database so it can identify packages available for upgrade

Comment: I usually explain it this way: Your system keeps a local database of all the packages available from all the sources that it knows about. Apt must *update* that database so it can identify packages available for *upgrade*.

Comment: That's a much better explanation, indeed ^^

Comment: Thanks **ldias** for the user 535733 precision, and thanks **guntbert** for the correction, i'm not very good in english ^^